# Is it pythonic/Djangoic for Model A's methods to reference Model B?

Tags: django

Presume I have these classes:

```
class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

    def display_text(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {','.join([x.name for x in self.authors.all()])}"

class Author(models.model):

    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    def name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

Is it normal/acceptable/the standard way of doing things to have the attributes of one model refer to another this way?  This is a heated debate at work, with the two sides being "don't do that, it can promote query count leaks" and "this is much more readable than most alternatives".

Is there a community-standard take on this problem?  Citations and references sought.

Comment: Yea, however, it's `self.authors`, the reverse relation is `author_set` .

Comment: Good point!  Edited.  Do you have a citation/reference I can use to persuade people?

Comment: Yes, "There's no other solution."

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Well, you _can_ make layers of functions over your data that apply additional behavior; that's the dispute at work.

Comment: Well,  Achieving the same effect with less code and more readability is considered pythonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is both Pythonic and Djangoic. This can be demonstrated by the fact, that this pattern is used in Django itself.

```py
# django/contrib/admin/models.py

class LogEntry(models.Model):

    # Code omitted for brevity

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name=_('content type'),
        blank=True, null=True,
    )

    # Code omitted for brevity

    def get_edited_object(self):
        """Return the edited object represented by this log entry."""
        return self.content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.object_id)

    # Code omitted for brevity
```

The `LogEntry.get_edited_object()` method calls the `ContentType.get_object_for_this_type()` method.

```py
# django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py

class ContentType(models.Model):

    # Code omitted for brevity

    def get_object_for_this_type(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Return an object of this type for the keyword arguments given.
        Basically, this is a proxy around this object_type's get_object() model
        method. The ObjectNotExist exception, if thrown, will not be caught,
        so code that calls this method should catch it.
        """
        return self.model_class()._base_manager.using(self._state.db).get(**kwargs)

    # Code omitted for brevity
```

Using this pattern is both common and recommended. Functions that operate on your model instance should as much as possible be a method of that model class. This is just good Pythonic programming.

As Ahmed said...

> Yes, "There's no other solution."